# C# - Get the children of a list item of a listview using teststack white

Tags: c#, white-framework

So I have this LISTVIEW for example

listStudents:

```
[ID] [NAME        ] [AGE   ][SCHOOL  ] -> Header
1     Harry Potter       13   Hogwarts
2     Draco Malfoy       13   Hogwarts
```

This list view is from a third party app and I don't have the source code.

what I need is to get the complete row for example:
1 Harry Potter 13 Hogwarts

I use inspect to get the IDs. And I am using teststack.

this is the code I've tried:

```
var listItem = listStudents.Items.ElementAt(0);
```

the problem is, it only returns the 1st column of the row, which is the id. 
for example in the first row:
1

I checked the inspect and it shows:

```
[- "1" list item          ]
  [  + "Harry Potter" text]
  [  + "13" text          ]
  [  + "Hogwarts" text    ]
```

is there anyway to get these values?

Comment: Since you have multiple row/cols wouldn't it make sense that you have to access an entire indexed row? `Items[0].ElementAt[0]`?

Comment: @Tdorno. thanks, I tried that but it does not give the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The Items property returns a collection of the first columns text here is the code from white.

```
 public virtual List<string> Items
 {
     get
     {
         return Rows.Select(listViewRow => listViewRow.Cells[0].Text).ToList();
     }
 }
```

So you would want to use the rows proeprty instead.

```
 listView.Rows[0].Cells["ColumnName"]
```

This also support using index of the cell.

```
 listView.Rows[0].Cells[0]
```

Here is the example from the unit test I based my answer off of.

```
 void CellText()
 {
     using (var window = StartScenario("OpenListView", "ListViewWindow"))
     {
         var listView = window.Get<ListView>("ListView");
         ListViewRow first = listView.Rows[0];
         Assert.Equal("Search", first.Cells[0].Text);
         Assert.Equal("Google", first.Cells[1].Text);
         ListViewRow second = listView.Rows[1];
         Assert.Equal("Mail", second.Cells[0].Text);
         Assert.Equal("GMail", second.Cells[1].Text);
     }
 }
```